# Databricks standard edition Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

What does this mean using the Databricks premium edition?

How many workers do I have? and how many cores does each of the workers have?

[image]

**Update 1:**

[image]

Comment: Does community version come with such a huge config ? Anyways from the screenshot it looks like you have 1 Driver with 4 cores. Looks like you have Autoscaling enabled ? So the number of worker nodes will start at 2 and then increase upto 8 based on the load. Each worker node looks like it has 4 cores so number of cores is between 8 (i.e. 2 worker * 4 cores each) to 32 cores (8 workers * 4 cores each). Hope this helps...[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/create-cluster) might help..

Comment: So sorry. I updated the question. It is a premium edition. Many thanks for your classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databricks community edition always have clusters consisting of the single driver node. Your screenshot is for "normal" Databricks cluster that consists of driver with 4 cores and from 2 to 8 executors also having 4 cores each.  Depending on the workload size of the cluster will increase or decrease, but you'll have at least 2 executors when it's scaled down, and max 8 executors when it's scaled up. But you may have 4 or 6 executors as well, as scale up process is performed in steps.

Comment: I updated the question. Since I run the two versions :) So how can I know exactly how many workers currently running?

Comment: you can look into cluster configuration UI - in the same line where you configure min & max workers, you will see the current number of workers. You can also look into cluster event log in the same UI - it will show upscale & downscale events. You can also get the same information via [REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters.html#get).

Comment: So we have 2 workers.